# Disk iops spiking a lot in Percona 5.6.28 compared to 5.6.19

Tags: mysql, innodb, disk, percona

We recently upgraded from Percona 5.6.19 to 5.6.28 on our database servers. Comparatively the disk write iops on 5.6.28 is a lot spikier compared to 5.6.19.

I checked all the parameters in both versions in our Production environment and they are almost similar other than the paths and some newer variables introduced in Percona 5.6.28, but none of them seem to be related to the issue we are seeing.

I have attached the diff of variables between the server with 5.6.19 and 5.6.28.

Both these servers are sharded, so they both of them get very similar load on them and both of them are serving as master currently.

From what I can see the buffer pool dirty pages seems to be flushed more often in 5.6.28 compared to 5.6.19 and that is why I believe we are seeing the spikes.

Attached you will find the comparative graphs of buffer pool dirty pages for an period of 4 hours.

[Buffer pool dirty pages-bytes 5.6.19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyh6K.png)
[Buffer pool dirty pages-bytes 5.6.19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNS4t.png)

Following are the parameters set on both servers:
Percona 5.6.28

```
root@P5628 [(none)]> show global variables like 'version';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| version       | 5.6.28-76.1-log |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@P5628 [(none)]> show global variables like '%buffer%';
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size             | 8388608        |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 8              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_populate         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 47244640256    |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size       | 25             |
| innodb_change_buffering             | all            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size              | 33554432       |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576        |
| join_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| key_buffer_size                     | 67108864       |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 134217728      |
| net_buffer_length                   | 16384          |
| preload_buffer_size                 | 32768          |
| read_buffer_size                    | 131072         |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                | 262144         |
| sort_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| sql_buffer_result                   | OFF            |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root@P5628 [(none)]> show global variables like '%dirty%';
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                  | Value |
+--------------------------------+-------+
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct     | 75    |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm | 0     |
+--------------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root@P5628 [(none)]> show global variables like '%flush%';
+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name                             | Value               |
+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time               | 0                   |
| flush                                     | OFF                 |
| flush_time                                | 0                   |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                  | ON                  |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm              | 10                  |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout               | 1                   |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 2                   |
| innodb_flush_method                       | O_DIRECT            |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                    | 0                   |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                 | 30                  |
| innodb_foreground_preflush                | exponential_backoff |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON                  |
+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Percoan 5.6.19

```
root@P5619 [(none)]> show global variables like 'version';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| version       | 5.6.19-67.0-log |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@P5619 [(none)]> show global variables like '%buffer%';
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size             | 8388608        |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 8              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_populate         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 47244640256    |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size       | 25             |
| innodb_change_buffering             | all            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size              | 33554432       |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576        |
| join_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| key_buffer_size                     | 67108864       |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 134217728      |
| net_buffer_length                   | 16384          |
| preload_buffer_size                 | 32768          |
| read_buffer_size                    | 131072         |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                | 262144         |
| sort_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| sql_buffer_result                   | OFF            |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root@P5619 [(none)]> show global variables like '%dirty%';
+--------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                  | Value |
+--------------------------------+-------+
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct     | 75    |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm | 0     |
+--------------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root@P5619 [(none)]> show global variables like '%flush%';
+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name                             | Value               |
+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| audit_json_file_flush                     | OFF                 |
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time               | 0                   |
| flush                                     | OFF                 |
| flush_time                                | 0                   |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                  | ON                  |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm              | 10                  |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout               | 1                   |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 2                   |
| innodb_flush_method                       | O_DIRECT            |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                    | 0                   |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                 | 30                  |
| innodb_foreground_preflush                | exponential_backoff |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON                  |
+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please let me know if any of you have seen similar issue and what could be the cause of this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Has anything changed between how dirty pages are flushed between 5.6.19 and 5.6.28? Any information will help. Thanks!

Comment: Does the server have 64B of ram?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%change_buffer%';`

Comment: Could post the entire `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` for both machines (after running for at least a day)?  There may be other things worth checking on.

Comment: Does the server have 64B of ram? Both servers have 512G of RAM, but both of them are running 8 instances on each. I have posted the `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'` from both in the details.

Comment: And you are running only one instance at a time when you are measuring the IOPs?  Or somehow the VM segregates the IOPs adequately?

Comment: We are tracking the IOPs by host, so it is for all 8 instances. But the dirty pages flushed graph is similar for all.